# How to merge several rows with event data from multiple columns when based on unique character column?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, aggregate

Let's say I have `d`:

```
> d
  pnr age.hl age.hl.time kon.hl kon.hl.time sen.hl sen.hl.time mix.hl mix.hl.time
1   A      0  2018-12-31      1  2011-02-01      0  2018-12-31      0  2018-12-31
2   A      1  2013-10-31      0  2018-12-31      0  2018-12-31      1  2013-10-31
3   A      0  2018-12-31      0  2018-12-31      1  2016-09-30      0  2018-12-31
4   B      0  2018-12-31      0  2018-12-31      1  2004-04-30      0  2018-12-31
5   C      0  2018-12-31      0  2018-12-31      0  2018-12-31      1  2006-01-17
6   C      1  2008-07-31      0  2018-12-31      1  2009-01-31      0  2018-12-31
```

`d$pnr` is a unique patient identifier. `age.hl`, `kon.hl`, `sen.hl` and `mix.hl` denote different diseases and their corresponding time variable. All patients are censored at `2018-12-31` if 0 event occured.

If 1 occur in any column, it cannot occur again in the *same* column.

I need to merge rows, so `d$pnr` only occur one time. I.e, event data/information from each column shall be merged to the same row.

I look for a solution in `dplyr`.

**Expected output**:

```
  pnr age.hl age.hl.time kon.hl kon.hl.time sen.hl sen.hl.time mix.hl mix.hl.time
1   A      1  2013-10-31      1  2011-02-01      1  2016-09-30      1  2013-10-31
2   B      0  2018-12-31      0  2018-12-31      1  2004-04-30      0  2018-12-31
3   C      1  2008-07-31      0  2018-12-31      1  2009-01-31      1  2006-01-17
```

**Data**

```
d <- data.frame(
  pnr = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "C", "C"),
  age.hl = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1),
  age.hl.time = c(as.Date("2018-12-31"), as.Date("2013-10-31"), as.Date("2018-12-31"),
                  as.Date("2018-12-31"), as.Date("2018-12-31"), as.Date("2008-07-31")),
  kon.hl = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
  kon.hl.time = c(as.Date("2011-02-01"), as.Date("2018-12-31"), as.Date("2018-12-31"),
                  as.Date("2018-12-31"), as.Date("2018-12-31"), as.Date("2018-12-31")),
  sen.hl = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1),
  sen.hl.time = c(as.Date("2018-12-31"), as.Date("2018-12-31"), as.Date("2016-09-30"),
                  as.Date("2004-04-30"), as.Date("2018-12-31"), as.Date("2009-01-31")),
  mix.hl = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0),
  mix.hl.time = c(as.Date("2018-12-31"), as.Date("2013-10-31"), as.Date("2018-12-31"),
                  as.Date("2018-12-31"), as.Date("2006-01-17"), as.Date("2018-12-31"))
)
```

Comment: What if there are 2 different dates for some patient and both his values are zeros?

Comment: Is this the case in the data I provided? Because I typed it in manually and could be a typo.

Comment: That would not be possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `which.max()`:

```r
library(dplyr)

d %>%
  summarise(across(ends_with("time"), ~ .x[which.max(get(sub(".time", "", cur_column())))]),
            across(ends_with("hl"), max),
            .by = pnr) %>%
  select(names(d))

#   pnr age.hl age.hl.time kon.hl kon.hl.time sen.hl sen.hl.time mix.hl mix.hl.time
# 1   A      1  2013-10-31      1  2011-02-01      1  2016-09-30      1  2013-10-31
# 2   B      0  2018-12-31      0  2018-12-31      1  2004-04-30      0  2018-12-31
# 3   C      1  2008-07-31      0  2018-12-31      1  2009-01-31      1  2006-01-17
```

**Note:** The function in the first `across()` involves the values in the second `across()`, so the two `across()` are **not** exchangeable.